# Facebook comment moderation issue

Tags: facebook, joomla2.5, facebook-comments

I want to use the Facebook comment plugin, so I flow this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)
I succeed to integrate the Plugin in my Joomla page. 
I added the meta tag below to my page's header:
`<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>`

The Plugin is working I can add comments to my content, but I can't moderate them in [moderation tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments).

PS: I'm using the plugin in my localhost but the URL in `data-href` is on line.
I tried to create a Facebook application and fill the `App domain` and "Web site URL" with the same URL that used in `data-href`.

Any hep?

Comment: Check your URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 2):

You added the wrong meta tag. If you want to moderate the comments in the [moderation tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments):

- you need to add `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>` with `YOUR_APPLICATION_ID` correctly set to your page's header,
- in the [app's settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), you will have to add administrators.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I have just to test it in my live server. But I don't understand why it didn't work in my local machine.